# Grant privileges for an Oracle package?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I have a `package A`, which uses some variables and procedures in another `package B` in the **same schema**. Now I want to move `package A` to a **new schema**. What privileges should I grant to the `new schema` for using the `package B` same way? What is the grant statement for that ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [GRANT](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/grant_revoke.php) to give `execute` privileges

```
grant execute on PACKAGE_B to new_schema;
```

Then, you need to ensure that any reference in package A includes the full path:

```
PACKAGE_B.SOME_PROC
```

It might be worth creating a public synonym in for the package, so that you can avoid referencing the schema too.